# Why is not ordering list of list correctly?

Tags: python, list, sorting

When I apply `sort` or `sorted` to the list of lists, Python does not order properly.
For example I want to order by `B1, B2, ..., B10, B11, ...` 
But Python order by `B1, B10, B11, B2, B20, B21, ...`
The list of list is bigger then the one I put here.

```
 def getKey(item):
     return item[0]

l = [['B3', '08:20', '08:50', ('LH233', 'Berlin', '08:20', '112', '203')], ['B10', '08:40', '08:55', ('AF76', 'Toulouse', '08:40', '57', '102')]]

l.sort(key=getKey) OR sorted(l, key=getKey)

Returns:

[['B10', '08:40', '08:55', ('AF76', 'Toulouse', '08:40', '57', '102')], ['B3', '08:20', '08:50', ('LH233', 'Berlin', '08:20', '112', '203')]]
```

Comment: is it possible for you to use `B01`, instead of `B1` ? if so then `string.zfill(int)` is something you might find useful for example: `"A".zfill(2) == "0A"`

Answer (score 2):

This is because, according to Python, `10` comes before `2`, since, in your example, you are actually doing string comparisons, and not numbers comparisons. One solution would be to convert that `string-numbers` to numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your keys are strings which are sorted in lexicographic order. To sort in the order you want, integer keys are required. One way of getting these is given below.

```
>>> l = [['B3', '08:20', '08:50', ('LH233', 'Berlin', '08:20', '112', '203')], ['B10', '08:40', '08:55', ('AF76', 'Toulouse', '08:40', '57', '102')]]
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x:int(x[0][1:]))
[['B3', '08:20', '08:50', ('LH233', 'Berlin', '08:20', '112', '203')], ['B10', '08:40', '08:55', ('AF76', 'Toulouse', '08:40', '57', '102')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make "B3" and "B10" into integers, 3 and 10 e.g.:

```
def getKey(item):    
    return int(item[0][1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Because its sorting by first number. Lists in list.

> B1-B10-B11-

1 first,1 and 0 second, 1 and 1 third..